# Add new line to text using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I knew this question is answered, but when I try this code in my batch file:

```
echo # Comment line>temp.txt
...
set /p a=" "
echo Text %x% %y% %a%>>temp.txt
goto main_loopMouse
```

Then type some text at line `set /p a=" "`, it just leave the 'a' var blank "`Text 25 21` "

Anyone can help me this?

Comment: I think you want to use `set a= ` where there is a space (or two or however many you need after the `=` symbol.

Comment: No, what I want is get user's input `set /p a=" "` then put to new file.

Comment: If the value you enter ends with a digit, it can be seen as a source stream indicator for the redirection operator. Try with `>>temp.txt echo Text %x% %y% %a%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use delayedexpansion so

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p a=Enter some text
echo Text %x% %y% !a! >> temp.txt
```

As the a 'var' still empty with no value when the line got executed